# renderer gridcolumn - '0' is not shown in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using EXTJS 6.2
I have a gridpanel with many columns. 
I have different renderers - they work fine. Only one renderer does not.

```
renderer = function(value) {
      return value || '';
};
```

Why does the gridcolumn stay empty, if value == '0'

If I add the following to my renderer

```
 renderer = function(value) {
       if (value == 0) {
            return value;
       }
       return value || '';
 }
```

'0' will be displayed. 
I don't understand why I have to add these rows
Can anybody explain that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your use of the logical operator || When it comes to yes 0 || return empty string because 0 is like false

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/350h)